# Laravel DomPDF error row not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

Am getting this error while generating pdf using DOMPDF

```
  The row #2 could not be found, please file an issue in the tracker wit
```

I can view the output as html in my view page.But PDF is not generating am getting the above error.I have two arrays for the table headings and the results. MY code as follows:

My code:

```
<table width="100%"  class="fullwidth border">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%"></th>
            <th width="10%"></th>
            @foreach($selected_fields_top as $key => $value)                       
                <th>{{ $value }}</th>
             @endforeach
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($selected_fields_left as $key => $value)                      
                        <tr><td><b>{{ $value }}</b></td>
                            <!-- <td> -->
                            @foreach($resultListLeft as $left_key => $valueArr) 
                                @foreach($valueArr as $k => $v)
                                       @if($v)
                                        <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <!-- <tr> -->
                                                    @if($valueArr[$value])
                                                    <td width="10%">{{$valueArr[$value]}}</td>
                                                    @else
                                                     <td width="10%">Data not available</td>
                                                    @endif
                                                    @foreach($resultListTop as $key => $TopvalueArr)
                                                        @if($key==$left_key)    
                                                        @foreach($TopvalueArr as $top_key => $top_value)
                                                               @if($top_value)
                                                                 <td width="10%">{{$top_value}}</td>
                                                                 @else
                                                                 <td width="10%">Data not available</td>
                                                                @endif
                                                        @endforeach
                                                        @endif
                                                    @endforeach 
                                                <!-- </tr> -->
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        <!-- </td> -->
                    @endforeach
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

i want to print the output like:-

```
                                  Top heading1   Topheading2


 Left heading 1  Left value       Top value      Top value
                 Left value       Top value      Top value
                 Left value       Top value      Top value
                 etc...           etc...         etc...


 Left heading 2  Left value       Top value      Top value
                 Left value       Top value      Top value
                 Left value       Top value      Top value
                 etc...           etc...         etc...
```

Comment: Kindly share your source code.

Comment: Can i get any help on this..?

Comment: In view am able to see the page in a table.But while generating PDF td , tr breaks.Not taking the full width i have given in html page.Is there any idea to share please help..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you have to var_dump the variable if they do contain such row.

Comment: In view am able to see the page in a table.But while generating PDF td , tr breaks.Not taking the full width i have given in html page.Is there any idea to share please help..Thanks

Comment: Have you used  <nobr>  text </nobr> tags?